# How to validate same field second time in bootstrapvalidator

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this iam validating servicedescription after onchange and it is forworking fine but whenever my text changes to otherthan "OTHER" and need validate Remarks in that only StringLength

This is my div

```
<div class="form-group" id="serviceDescription">
                                   <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Service Description:<span class="servicedescription hide" style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></label>
                                   <div class="col-sm-6">
                                       <textarea class="form-control" name="Remarks" id="Remarks" placeholder="Enter Service Description" rows="5"></textarea>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
```

This is my onchange

```
.on('change', '[name="ServiceID"]', function () {
    var Serviceid = parseInt($("#ServiceID").val());
    var skillsSelect = document.getElementById("ServiceID");
    var selectedText = skillsSelect.options[skillsSelect.selectedIndex].text;

    if (selectedText == "OTHER") {

        $(".servicedescription").removeClass("hide");
        $('#AddServicesForm').bootstrapValidator('enableFieldValida‌​tors','Remarks');
        $('#AddServicesForm').bootstrapValidator('validateField', 'Remarks');

    }

    else{
        $('#AddServicesForm').bootstrapValidator('enableFieldValidators', 'Remarks', false)
        $(".servicedescription").addClass("hide");
    } 
})
```

And this is my bootstrapvalidator

```
Remarks: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'Remarks is required and cannot be empty'
                            },
                            stringLength: {
                                min: 1,
                                max: 200,
                                message: 'Service Description must be 1 to 200 characters long'
                            },

                        }
                    },
```